# how to use async and await in koa?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, koa, koa-router

I have a created a simple login api but i'm getting 404 error. How i can solve this issue? My ctx body is not working. When i hit on postman it throws not found.

```
router.post('/login', async (ctx, next) => {

    var phone= ctx.request.body.phone;
    var password = ctx.request.body.password;


        await ctx.app.pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone= $1",
            [`${phone}`],
            async (err, result) => {
               if (result) {
                   await bcrypt.compare(password, result.rows[0].password).then(function (res) {

                        if (res === true) {
                            ctx.body = {
                                status: 200,
                                message: "login successfully",
                                data: result.rows[0],
                            };
                        }else{
                            ctx.body = {
                                status: 400,
                                message: "Incorrect password! Try again.",
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    ctx.body = {
                        status: 400,
                        message: "Invalid phone",
                    }
                }
            });
});
```

Comment: What database lib are you using?
Most probably you are adding a callback function as a parameter of query. Thats why it doesn't wait for a response.

const res = await ctx.app.pool.query("select..",["param])
if(res) {
// do stuff here
}

Comment: @Tobias I'm using postgresql database and no library just using raw queries

Comment: so you are using 'pg' node module?
Just don't pass a callback function as you did.
Look at my previous response

Comment: @TobiasLins I tried but if i put wrong phone then it throws 500 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First don't mix async with callbacks & `then`

Use `const res = await somepromise()`

You used a callback for the query and a `then` for bcrypt.compare instead of awaiting it

```js
router.post('/login', async (ctx, next) => {
  const phone= ctx.request.body.phone;
  const password = ctx.request.body.password;
  const result =  await ctx.app.pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone= $1",  [`${phone}`])

  if (result) {
     const pwCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(password, result.rows[0].password)
     if (pwCorrect === true) {
        ctx.body = {
           status: 200,
           message: "login successfully",
           data: result.rows[0],
        };
     }else{
         ctx.body = {
           status: 400,
           message: "Incorrect password! Try again.",
         }
     }
  } else{
      ctx.body = {
        status: 400,
        message: "Invalid phone",
      }

});
```

Comment: It is not clear when koa sends a response back to the client. After the middleware function returns? How about when the middleware function has returned but `body` has not been set yet? It might have been scheduled to be set by an asynchronous callback (e.g. by an async timer set by `setTimeout`)